# Can I use seeds in Minecraft PE on my iPad to get my worlds from my iPad to my iPod?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I type the seed in on my iPod of my iPads world will I get the whole world?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this.  However, on the new device you typed the seed into, you will get the same world as it was before you started building things or digging any blocks up (just to be clear).

From [the Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)):

> This algorithm will output a pseudo-random value that is then used to determine what the world will look like. **However, the algorithm will always end up with the same value if the starting point (seed) that the algorithm uses is the same number**.

Typing in the same exact seed should give you the same exact map (so long as it is the same version of Minecraft). Skewing it in anyway will give you an entirely different map.

Comment: Wait I built a whole town so it won’t be there

Comment: @Lauren no it won't.